# Schengen visa requirements for a minor

Tags: visas, schengen

I am turning 18 on 13th of July but my visa interview is on 8th of July. So when I applied on the visa I typed that I am a minor and included information about my father. I have read that there are certain conditions and my parents, both mother and father, have to sign on the application.

But the problem here is that my father is working abroad and I can't get his signature any sooner but I can my mum's (this also applied on the parental authorization). Will this make any difference and will they insist on having my father's signature?

Comment: When is your intended travel date? Is it before or after your 18th birthday?

Comment: Certainly he can fax an authorisation.  You can ask for a concession based upon the circumstances you have described.

Comment: @Willeke I am travelling ceratinly after turning 18 beacuse my interview in on 8th and my birthday is 13th so i will have no time to travel in 5 days if i have my visa in any ways

Comment: @GayotFow i'll call the embassy here but i hope that they don't insist on having his signature because there is no way to have it but do i have to give documents yo rove that he's travelling abroad if he couldn't fax the authorization ...thank you

Answer (score 1):

In normal cases the parental authorisation must have a wet signature, but if obtaining this is unreasonable they may be able to work with a faxed authorisation and proof that the parent is abroad.

To demonstrate that it is unreasonable, you can show exhibits proving his absence.  But keep in mind that they will be giving a concession and they have the right to insist your father post an authorisation with a wet signature.